TSA PreCheck for elderly's caregiver
My 85-year-old father will be flying with a caregiver. He has TSA PreCheck, they do not. Can the caregiver go through the TSA PreCheck with him?

My experience is that it can go either way. If they don't get a Pre on their boarding pass, they should both go through the regular lane. The elderly will be getting the "Pre" treatment for most parts anyway, even if they're not recognized as "Pre" in the regular lane, since older folks are not required to take off shoes and such.
